# How to test SSO for Google Apps marketplace without Google App account

Tags: google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

Is there possibility to test application before posting it to Google Apps marketplace for approving?

As I know, basic requirements is to support Single SignOn, but if I currently haven't Google app account, can I test my implementation of Single SignOn integration in other way? Is there some google test account, or test SSO portal?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but why don't you create a Google Apps account. The [basic version is free](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html) for upto 10 accounts. All you need is a domain name.

Comment: Yes, but I haven't any DNS records. Seems that anyway I need DNS records, and I will get it. Thanks.